# Is TIdHashSHA1.HashStream broken in Delphi 2010?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, indy

After a painful debugging session I found that `TIdHashSHA1.HashStream` does not respect its `ASize` argument. Consider the following code:

```
var
  Hasher: TIdHashSHA1;
  MS: TMemoryStream;
begin
  MS := TMemoryStream.Create;
  Hasher := TIdHashSHA1.Create;
  try
    MS.LoadFromFile('C:\windows\notepad.exe');
    MS.Position := 0;
    ShowMessage(Hasher.HashStreamAsHex(MS));
    MS.Position := 0;
    ShowMessage(Hasher.HashStreamAsHex(MS, 0, MS.Size - 10));
  finally
    Hasher.Free;
    MS.Free;
  end;
end;
```

The results are the same. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong? If it is a bug indeed, what is the easiest way to get around it without copying the part of the stream I want hashed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that `TIdHashSHA1` (specifically, the `TIdHashSHA1.NativeGetHashBytes()` method) is ignoring the `ASize` parameter.  It reads from the input stream until fewer than 64 bytes are read, however long that takes.  That does appear to be a bug that needs to be fixed.  It should not be reading more than actually requested.  I have opened tickets in Indy's bug trackers for that.

Since the bug is in the same method that is doing the actual hashing of data, the only workaround you can do until I release an official fix would be to fix `NativeGetHashBytes()` yourself in `IdHashSHA.pas` and then recompile Indy (or, if you are not using runtime packages, you can make a local copy of `IdHashSHA.pas` and add it to your project, then fix the copy).

Comment: @ThijsvanDien: I have checked in an update to `TIdHashSHA1` in Indy's SVN. Once you have confirmed the fix is working, I will close the tickets.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Could you provide a direct link please? I was browsing the online SVN but https://svn.atozed.com:444/svn/Indy10/trunk/Lib/Protocols/IdHashSHA1.pas was last updated in 2003...?

Comment: @ThijsvanDien: you are looking at old commit comments from a VCS system that Indy stopped using years ago. That VCS stored commit comments directly in source files. SVN does not do that. Both `IdHashSHA.pas` and `IdHashSHA1.pas` were updated earlier today (5071 is the current revision number).

Comment: Just downloaded the SVN. At first sight it seems to work properly now, but I think I'd need to write a serious unit test before I trust a heavily revised component that is at the core of my applications.

Answer (score 1):

Now it has been confirmed to be a bug, I made a workaround using a [TGpStreamWindow](http://www.thedelphigeek.com/2007/05/stream-me-river.html).